# How to load data into RecyclerView while scrolling

Tags: java, android, adapter

I am using RecyclerView, and its calling all the data items, which are not even seen by user. So how can i load only that item which are seen by user, or load while scrolling

XML:

```xml
  <androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/post_ImagesRecyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_margin="5dp"
    android:background="@color/grey_bg"
    android:nestedScrollingEnabled="false"/>
```

Java:

```java
    postAdapter = new PostAdapter(context, false, false, postList, this, 1, loadType);
        LinearLayoutManager postListManager = new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity(), LinearLayoutManager.VERTICAL, false);
        post.setLayoutManager(postListManager);
        post.setAdapter(postAdapter);
```

Answer (score 1):

As it's said in official documentation,

> The views in the list are represented by view holder objects. These objects are instances of a class you define by extending RecyclerView.ViewHolder. Each view holder is in charge of displaying a single item with a view. For example, if your list shows music collection, each view holder might represent a single album. The RecyclerView creates only as many view holders as are needed to display the on-screen portion of the dynamic content, plus a few extra. As the user scrolls through the list, the RecyclerView takes the off-screen views and rebinds them to the data which is scrolling onto the screen.

So, if you use RecyclerView you shouldn't worry about this problem